# Отличие оконных функций от агрегатных

Tags: sql, psql

Правильно ли я понимаю, что основное отличие оконных функций от агрегатных в том, что в агрегатных функциях результатом каждой группы является только одна строка. Но что тогда с оконными?

Comment: Оконные считают то же, что агрегатные но подставляют результат в каждую исходную строку данных

Comment: Ну и формулировка что результатом агрегатных является одна строка не совсем верная. строка все равно останется одна, group by постарается. А агрегатная функция соберет для этой строки результат с исходных строк

Comment: Оконные функции помимо набора строк принимают порядок и текущую строку.